# Storing external libs' objects with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, bson

I am trying to write a play2.1 application using MongoDB and ReactiveMongo. one of my models have members of an external library (specifically SecureSocial userid and passwordinfo, but generally). 
my question is - what BSON type do i store them under?

```
case class User{
    firstName: String, 
    lastName: String,
    authMethod: AuthenticationMethod,
    avatarUrl: Option[String] = None, 
    oAuth1Info: Option[OAuth1Info] = None,
    oAuth2Info: Option[OAuth2Info] = None,
}

  implicit object UserBSONReader extends BSONReader[User] {
    def fromBSON(document: BSONDocument) :Role = {
      val doc = document.toTraversable
      User(
        doc.getAs[BSONObjectID]("_id"),
        doc.getAs[BSONString]("email").get.value,
        doc.getAs[**?????????**]("passwordInfo").get.value,
        doc.getAs[BSONString]("firstName").get.value,
        doc.getAs[BSONString]("lastName").get.value,
        doc.getAs[**?????????**]("authMethod").get.value,
```

...

Comment: You simply need to define Bson Reader/Writer for there custom types (like UserBSONReader)

Comment: yup, already started doing that, and it's a bit ugly because of Option[]'s adn such. I was hoping for something more elegant (and internal to Reactive...)